# CMake - Multiple subdirectories without multiple CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

**Description**

I'm currently creating a program that would turn a model from simulink and matlab into an [FMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_Mock-up_Interface).

As I want to automate the process as much as possible I want to also automate the build process for both an EXE, to extract information in the C-API supplied, and later a DLL for the FMU. My plan was to do this with CMake, which is why I'm here. As I know the layout of the code generation (See further down), I could go ahead and make multiple CMakeLists and just have a part of my python script paste them into their repsective folders. BUT, I wanted to make sure this was the only way of doing it (Multiple CMakeLists) before going ahead.

**Question**

Is there *anyway* to only have one CMakeLists with many multiple categories? Do I just include all subfolders that include files with target_include_directories() or have I understood that completely wrong? Is there a way to make target_include_directories() to also include subfolders?

My current directory looks like this:

```
\---CMakeListExperiment 
|   main.c
|   CMakeLists.txt <--- Is it possible to make this the only CMakeLists?
|   
+---R2017b
|   |   
|   |   
|   +---extern
|   |   \---include
|   |           tmwtypes.h
|   |           
|   +---rtw
|   |   \---c
|   |       \---src
|   |           |   rt_logging.h
|   |           |   rtw_capi.h
|   |           |   rtw_modelmap_logging.h
|   |           |   rt_logging.c
|   |           |   rt_mxclassid.h
|   |           |   rt_logging_mmi.c
|   |           |   rtw_modelmap.h
|   |           |   rt_logging_mmi.h
|   |           |   rtw_modelmap_utils.c
|   |           |   
|   |           +---common
|   |           |       rt_main.c
|   |           |       
|   |           \---ext_mode
|   |               \---common
|   |                       ext_work.h
|   |                       
|   \---simulink
|       \---include
|               rtw_matlogging.h
|               sysran_types.h
|               rtw_extmode.h
|               sl_sample_time_defs.h
|               simstruc_types.h
|               sl_types_def.h
|               rtw_solver.h
|               rtw_continuous.h
|               
+---multi_grt_rtw 
|       rtGetInf.c
|       rtwtypes.h
|       rt_nonfinite.h
|       multiword_types.h
|       multi_capi.h
|       rtmodel.h
|       buildInfo.mat
|       defines.txt
|       rtGetNaN.h
|       builtin_typeid_types.h
|       rt_nonfinite.c
|       multi_capi.c
|       rtGetNaN.c
|       multi.h
|       multi_capi_host.h
|       rtGetInf.h
|       multi_private.h
|       multi_types.h
|       multi_data.c
|       multi.c
```

I'm usually very bad at explaining things, so if there's any confusion let me know. I'm also new to posting at SO, which is why I would love feedback. Cheers

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried the following CMakeLists. I can get this working if I move all sourcefiles inside *"/multi_grt_rtw/*, but will fail if these files are in their folders that comes produced by matlab. Fail as in "*can't find files*".

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(hello-vsc C)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES_NORMAL RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "multi_grt_rtw/*.c")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES_MATLAB RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "R2017b/*.c")
set(SOURCE main.c)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/multi_grt_rtw)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/R2017b)
add_executable(main ${SOURCE} ${SOURCES_NORMAL} ${SOURCES_MATLAB})
```

My guess is that include_directories is not recursive (Not searching subdirectories for sourcefiles), so my question is if there's any way to do that? Make include_directories recursive?

The other two, in theory?, working options are

A) As everything is always produced the same, write all CMakeLists needed and copy them, with a script, to correct folder during execution.

B) Add multiple include_directories() to main directory CMakeLists

Now when I have had some time away from work, I guess my question is a bit weird. But it would still be intresting finding out if include_directories() could be used in the way I want it to be, as I can't find much information about it.

Comment: "Is there anyway to only have one CMakeLists with many multiple categories?" - Yes, you may have only one `CMakeLists.txt` and create as many executables, libraries or other custom targets in it as you want. What is your problem? Probably, you have already tried single-`CMakeLists.txt` approach, and have faced with some errors you cannot resolve. If so, ask about these errors (by providing error messages and the code which cause them).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand the confusion. Added some more information in case any helps. As I added in my edit aswell, I now understand that my question is a bit weird. Sorry about that.

Comment: Include directories are never intended to be recursive. You should include only directories, which contains headers with needed names.  E.g. if you have file `include/foo/bar.h` and include it in your code with `#include foo/bar.h`, you should include directory `include` but not `include/foo`.